# How to make a customize php code to login into wordpress?( wordpress password encryption)

Tags: php, wordpress, encryption, authentication, md5

I face this problem while creating a customized form using php.I was inserting the password and convert it into MD5 encryption and then tried matching the password saved in "wp_users" table which is already encrypted.

I tried it converting the password using php MD5() function which was not matching with the saved password in the wp_users table

After doing lots of searches i found the solution wp_check_password() and that fix my issue. 
The code is mentioned in the answer

Comment: Even if you self-answer, the question should be a good question that is answerable. You say you had problems with `MD5()`, but don't go into detail and don't provide code. Therefore I voted to close as off-topic. Also, don't reference answers from your question. Remove that last paragraph from your question.

Answer (score 0):

wp_check_password is a wordpress function which gets the normal text password and converts it into the md5 encyption to match it with the saved password in the wp_users table.
referece : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_check_password

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/class-phpass.php'); // neccessary to add these files

$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

$user = get_user_by('email', $email );

if($user && wp_check_password( $pass, $user->data->user_pass, $user->ID)){
     echo "successfully login"; 
}
else
{
    echo "user login failed!";
}
```